# Angular Material - additional color palettes

Tags: css, angular, colors, themes

Im using Angular Material (https://material.angular.io/) and have successfully changed my color palettes.
Unfortunately, I need more palettes inside my theme than the three (primary, accent, warn) ones I get by default.

I would like to style my components like this:

```
<md-checkbox color="warn"></md-checkbox>
<md-checkbox color="secondary"></md-checkbox>
<md-checkbox color="customName"></md-checkbox>
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You can create additional material themes. See `example of defining multiple themes` at https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651937/angular-material-how-to-set-background-color-without-css

Comment: @Ploppy I dont want multiple themes, I want multiple palettes in my theme.

Comment: @DanielCooke this seems like it's for Angular 1. Is this possible in Angular 2?

Comment: @Thomas my bad - you are right that is for angular js.

Comment: Hi did you get any luck doing so?

Comment: This is still not supported, unfortunately. We coped by creating multiple themes wrapped in a "namespace" and applying those where needed.